# Filtering rows recursively in sqlite3/python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite query from an external source that will have an unknown number of WHERE clauses. There will be a limited number of types of clauses (and I know in advance what types they can be), but how many of each type is unknown until I actually receive the query.

I thought this would be an easy problem to solve until I actually got to it.

I can think of a couple of possible solutions. I could specify a long SELECT query with lots of different WHERE clauses for each type of selection, and fill those in with `1=1` when there's not enough selections given to fill them all up. But that's ugly code, and doesn't react well when more space is needed than is given.

I could instead not do this in pure SQL, but instead use a recursive Python function that iterates over the queries and successively filters the results. This is psuedocode that doesn't come close to running successfully:

```py
queries = (list of queries from external source)
return filter_results(conn.cursor(), (database), queries)

def filter_results(cursor, results, queries):
    if len(queries) == 0:
        return results_so_far
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {}".format(results, queries.pop(0)))
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return filter_results(cursor, results, queries)
```

As you can see I've fluffed over passing the database into the function, and I'm well aware that I won't be able to pass an SQL query to the result of `cursor.fetchall()`. At some point I'd either be trying to emulate SQL in Python, or exposing myself to SQL injection.

I'm either grossly overthinking this or trying to solve the unsolvable. I highly suspect it's the former. What's the correct approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a query building tool. In this case [PyPika](https://github.com/kayak/pypika) was the right tool.